# Missing about pages

Tags: recycle-bin, userprofiles

Im new to SharePoint so forgive my lack of knowlege.

I created a few top level sites, which I could see user profiles on. I decided to remove a couple sites to be sure of how the recycle bin acted. One of the sites I removed was /my and subsequently I now have no user profiles.

Further complicating this is the fact that the deleted /my site was not sent to the recycle bin.

Have I buggered this thing or is there an easy recovery available?

Thanks in advance.

Pete

Comment: Are you using SharePoint Online? Or any other version of SharePoint?

Answer (score 0):

You buggered your install for your purposes.  Since you don’t really have that much time or content built into it at this stage, I would advise against attempting to rebuild the my sites and just start over fresh with the knowledge that you should not do what you apparently did.

Comment: Thanks for the response. You are correct about the time and content investment, however, I don’t have ready access to the install media, this is actually an educational installation, so my instructor has the media.  I could bring my server back into school, but that is a heavy alternative, and rebuilding the my sites would be a valuable experience unless it is possible to render the whole install useless. Is it overly complicated?

Comment: Having done many SP installs over the years, I can definitively tell you that initial install and subsequent patching are the most sensitive times for your environment.

Comment: You could attempt a repair, but I doubt that will fix your issue.

Comment: If it was me, I would start fresh from an install - but if you don’t have media, there is always the ability to install from Microsoft web site.

Comment: Also - By the way - sorry for the excessive comments I’m pressing send on the mobile app in iOS when I mean to insert a line break and I keep forgetting there are no line breaks In comments.  Nonetheless, check the recycle bin in the admin site.  It’s a global recycle bin.  (I never asked, which version of SP are you working with?)

Comment: Thanks for all the responses, hehe. 
I actually fixed the issue this morning. In the manage user profiles section I cleared the personal site field, then recreated the /my site collection. Once the site was recreated the about me pages resolved again.